# Non standard interaction among two tables to avoid very large merge

Tags: python, join, merge, pandas, binary-search

Suppose I have two tables `A` and `B`.

Table `A` has a multi-level index `(a, b)` and one column (ts).
`b` determines univocally ts.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
     [('a', 'x', 4), 
      ('a', 'y', 6), 
      ('a', 'z', 5), 
      ('b', 'x', 4), 
      ('b', 'z', 5), 
      ('c', 'y', 6)], 
     columns=['a', 'b', 'ts']).set_index(['a', 'b'])
AA = A.reset_index()
```

Table `B` is another one-column (ts) table with non-unique index (`a`).
The ts's are sorted "inside" each group, i.e., `B.ix[x]` is sorted for each x.
Moreover, there is *always* a value in `B.ix[x]` that is greater than or equal to
the values in `A`.

```
B = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(a=list('aaaaabbcccccc'), 
         ts=[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9])).set_index('a')
```

The semantics in this is that `B` contains observations of occurrences of an event of type indicated by the index.

I would like to find from `B` the timestamp of the first occurrence of each event type after the timestamp specified in `A` for each value of `b`. In other words, I would like to get a table with the same shape of `A`, that instead of ts contains the "minimum value occurring after ts" as specified by table `B`.

So, my goal would be:

```
C: 
('a', 'x') 4
('a', 'y') 7
('a', 'z') 5
('b', 'x') 7
('b', 'z') 7
('c', 'y') 8
```

I have some working code, but is terribly slow.

```
C = AA.apply(lambda row: (
    row[0], 
    row[1], 
    B.ix[row[0]].irow(np.searchsorted(B.ts[row[0]], row[2]))), axis=1).set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

Profiling shows the culprit is obviously `B.ix[row[0]].irow(np.searchsorted(B.ts[row[0]], row[2])))`. However, standard solutions using merge/join would take too much RAM in the long run.

Consider that now I have 1000 `a`'s, assume constant the average number of b's per a (probably 100-200), and consider that the number of observations per a is probably in the order of 300. In production I will have 1000 more `a`'s.

`1,000,000 x 200 x 300 = 60,000,000,000` rows

may be a bit too much to keep in RAM, especially considering that the data I need is perfectly described by a C like the one I discussed above.

How would I improve the performance?

Comment: The real problem is this line: `np.searchsorted(B.ts[row[0]], row[2]))` Figure out how to pre-sort the data, and it'll go much faster.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto The data is ``presorted''. Is a pre-requisite for searchsorted. Each call to searchsorted is log(n), where n is on average the number of observations for each a, i.e. ~300, not too much. Moreover, since B is used by all the different A.a, I cannot do additional pre-processing, without using much more memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing sample data.  I've updated this answer with general
suggestions given anticipated array sizes in the 100's of million.

1. Line profile

   Line profiling the guts of your lambda function shows that most time is spent
   in B.ix[] (which has been refactored here to only be called once).

   ```
   In [91]: lprun -f stack.foo1 AA.apply(stack.foo1, B=B, axis=1)
   Timer unit: 1e-06 s

   File: stack.py
   Function: foo1 at line 4
   Total time: 0.006651 s

   Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   ==============================================================
        4                                           def foo1(row, B):
        5         6         6158   1026.3     92.6      subset = B.ix[row[0]].ts
        6         6          418     69.7      6.3      idx = np.searchsorted(subset, row[2])
        7         6           56      9.3      0.8      val = subset.irow(idx)
        8         6           19      3.2      0.3      return val
   ```
2. Consider built-in data types and raw numpy arrays over higher-level constructs.

   Since B behaves like a dict here and the same key is accessed many times, let's compare df.ix to a normal Python
   dictionary (precomputed elsewhere).  A dictionary with 1M keys (unique A values) should only require ~34MB (33% capacity: 3 * 1e6 * 12 bytes).

   ```
   In [102]: timeit B.ix['a']
   10000 loops, best of 3: 122 us per loop

   In [103]: timeit dct['a']
   10000000 loops, best of 3: 53.2 ns per loop
   ```
3. Replace function calls with loops

   The last major improvement I can think of would be to replace df.apply() with a for loop to avoid calling any function 200M times (or however large A is).

Hopefully these ideas help.

---

Original, expressive solution, though not memory efficient:

```
In [5]: CC = AA.merge(B, left_on='a', right_index=True)

In [6]: CC[CC.ts_x <= CC.ts_y].groupby(['a', 'b']).first()
Out[6]: 
     ts_x  ts_y
a b            
a x     4     4
  y     6     7
  z     5     5
b x     4     7
  z     5     7
c y     6     8
```

Comment: This is slightly faster than original, but there is till a lot of overhead (for me 4ms for the merge and 2.5ms for the second line). Probably easier to maintain than the numpy solution I gave.

Comment: Many thanks! I was under the impression that apply was preferable to loops. Looking at the source, I'm not that sure, as it is just regular python with more functionality than the one I need. Moreover, I assumed that Pandas indexes provided enough performance. A dict is just perfect -- I just have to find the way to put the data in the files as a dict instead than as df, since originally it was precisely a dict --

Comment: Well, your "expressive, not memory efficient solution" actually is 30 time faster than mine with my smaller dataset. I'm going to try it with the middle dataset. For the large one, I guess I'll have to change code anyway, because of several other issues.

Comment: Bad news. On the middle-size data set (which is 10^3 times smaller than the real one) I terminated disk-space because of virtual memory. That was a dict-based solution. Not good. I have definitely to move towards some HDF based solution or change the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Not sure I follow why you need an HDF solution if you're able to hold both A and B (as a dict and/or dataframe) in memory, unless those structures alone are borderline too large.

Comment: My guess is that A may need to be HDF'd in any case. Thing is, working with plain pandas is just so easier that it was worth trying.

Comment: Essentially: 'my solution' + your 'dict-based' suggestion takes 10 minutes -- too long for me, it's just O(n log n), should be faster, I'm probably doing something not clever somewhere -- the other solutions thrash the memory completely. So I'd probably better work on paper until I reformulate the problem in a more acceptable form.

Comment: That's fair -- feel free to update the question with latest code if you think it can be improved.  pandas seems to have a nice interface with HDF, including query support, when/if you move in that direction.

Comment: Ok. As for now, I inserted a hook so that the value I need is directly inserted in table A. It takes more space on disk and always uses more RAM. Moreover, the process that generates the tables takes roughly 4 times the time. However, memory does not blow up when I analyze stuff. Moreover, since is just on the same table, when I move to HDF it will not take additional effort. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Another option using numpy's boolean array notation, which seems an order of magnitude faster than the original (in this tiny example, and I suspect it'll be even better on larger datasets...):
*I suspect this is largely because picking the minimum is much faster task than sorting.*

```
In [11]: AA.apply(lambda row: (B.ts.values[(B.ts.values >= row['ts']) &
                                           (B.index == row['a'])].min()),
                          axis=1)
Out[11]: 
0    4
1    7
2    5
3    7
4    7
5    8

In [12]: %timeit AA.apply(lambda row: (B.ts.values[(B.ts.values >= row['ts']) &(B.index == row['a'])].min()), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop
```

This seems like the fastest method if you were to simply adding this as a column to `AA`.

If you were creating a new dataframe as in you example - trying to test this "fairly" - it is slower (but still twice as fast as the original):

```
In [13]: %timeit C = AA.apply(lambda row: (row[0], row[1], B.ix[row[0]].irow(np.searchsorted(B.ts[row[0]], row[2]))), axis=1).set_index(['a', 'b'])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit C = AA.apply(lambda row: (row[0], x[1], B.ts.values[(B.ts.values >= row['ts']) & (B.index == row['a'])].min()), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice job, though as I think more, both lambda functions and boolean notation probably won't scale well enough for the production sizes given: ~200M for A and ~300M for B.  I am recomposing with few suggestions for the OP.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm exploring this solution. I'm getting back when I have some additional info.